# CakePHP ajax form submit before and complete will not work for displaying animated gif

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, prototypejs

I"m using prototype I've tested ALL possibble scenarios, and my busy indicator WILL not show no matter what. I've cross browser tested no luck.

```
<?php 
echo $ajax->submit('Submit', array('url'=> array('controller'=>'records',        'action'=>'add'), 'update' => 'ajax_div', 
'evalScripts' => true,
'before' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('show', array('buffer' => false)),
'complete' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('hide', array('buffer' =>   false))));
?>

<?php echo $this->Html->image('ajax-loader.gif', array('id'=>'busy-indicator')); ?>
```

Comment: And I've tested the image path by removing my display: none; css..

Comment: do those statements work on say an alert() ? The problem seems 2fold, firstly the js call then the css which could make a difference to how it works.

Comment: Gevious, yes tested alert() already and works OK: ...'before' => $this->Js->alert('hey you!'),...

Comment: Here is my javascript output for  my alert test: Event.observe("submit69954697", 'click', function(event) { $("busy-indicator").show();; new Ajax.Updater('ajax_div','/php/records_1/records/add', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(Event.element(event).form), requestHeaders:['X-Update', 'ajax_div']}); alert("hey you!");; }, false);

Comment: Is it possible the request is being processed too fast, and thus the indicator does not even have a split second to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. I finally got this working. The manual had no indication of this method but it works like a charm for prototype:

```
<?php 
echo $ajax->submit('Submit', 
  array('url'=> array('controller'=>'records',
   'action'=>'add'), 'update' => 'ajax_div', 
   'evalScripts' => true,
   'loading' => 'Element.show(\'busy-indicator\')',
   'success' => 'Element.hide(\'busy-indicator\')'));
?>
```