# cakephp updating elements

Tags: ajax, cakephp, element

I have an index view which has some elements on it .

index controller code;

```
    $userID = $this->Authsome->get('id');       
$qnotes = $this->Qnote->getnotes($userID);  
$this->set('qnotes', $qnotes)
$this->render();
```

elements have been added to the page using

index view code

```
<?php echo $this->element('lsidebar'); ?>
```

now the Issue is I also Have an add controller.

add controller code

```
    function add() {  
    if(!empty($this->data)) {      
        unset($this->Qnote->Step->validate['qnote_id']);
        $this->Qnote->saveAll($this->data); 
        $this->Session->setFlash('New Note Template has been added.','flash_normal');


    }       
}
```

now what I am trying to achieve is once I add a Qnote i want the element('lsidebar') updated 
for the new Qnote.

I am Using the Ajax helper. found at http://www.cakephp.bee.pl/

also Here the add qnote View Code :

```
<?php echo $ajax->submit(
'Submit', array(
    'url' => array(
        'controller'=>'qnotes',
        'action'=>'add')

));
```

I know its sound like a noob question . can Somebody point me in the right direction atleast. 
I have tried everything i could think off. I bet the solution something easy which i didnt think off

help :)

Comment: `$this->set(compact('qnotes', $qnotes))` is nonsense, use either `$this->set(compact('qnotes'))`, its equivalent `$this->set(array('qnotes' => $qnotes))` or `$this->set('qnotes', $qnotes)`.

Comment: I'm also not sure how all those parts are related exactly. Your problem is you're adding a new entry via AJAX, and need to refresh the sidebar element upon success via AJAX as well?

Comment: $this->set('qnotes', $qnotes) 
ok fixed thanks.. 


yes something like that.or is there some other approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically update a sidebar with information that is submitted via ajax, there should be a "success" option in your ajax post that would allow you to fire a specific javascript action when the post is finished (or succeeds).  You should write a small javascript ajax function to reload the contents of your sidebar when the post succeeds.
See this other stackoverflow answer: [CakePHP ajax form submit before and complete will not work for displaying animated gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000922/cakephp-ajax-form-submit-before-and-complete-will-not-work-for-displaying-animate)